# How to avoid a view when the keyboard get opened | React-Native

Tags: react-native, keyboard

Does anybody know how I can get the behaviour.. that the **KeyboardAvoidingView** depends on the View which it is wrapped around.. and not on the TextInputFields..
Because I want that the whole View avoids the Keyboard and not only one TextInput..
I got a nearly acceptable behavior with the **behavior height** but there it also depends on the TextInputs and not on the View.. -> it doesn't look good ^^

In addition, I tried to create my own animations.. but android doesn't support the KeyboardWillHide/Show listener.. so it looks kind of wired if the animation starts after the keyboard is already there..

See how it currently behave: https://youtu.be/WxwaktqlkwA

Thank you ^^

Comment: have you try this package? https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: Yeah.. but there my container doesn't get shown at all.. and I can't add justifyContent: "flex-end" because its a scrollview..

Comment: you don't need the scrollview because the package is already scrollable, add flex-grow: 2 on your react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view contentContainerStyle props.

Comment: yeah.. I am not using any scroll-view but behind the scenes, this package is using a scrollview and if I am trying to apply styles to the KeyboardAwareScrollView component it applies the styles to the scrollview